# How pivot a dataframe to create 4 columns from existing 1 and inside each new cells calculate percentage?

Tags: pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
Country AgeRepartition     Count
USA     above 20           10
USA     less than 20       50
USA     above 50           40
Canada  above 20           50
Canada  less than 20       10
Canada  above 50           30
```

I would like to pivot this dataframe to have one column by age repartition type and have percentage as values.

Expected output:

```
Country above 20 less than 20 above 50  
USA     10%      50%          40%
Canada  55%      11%          33%
```

The percentage for example is how many people for USA are above 20 among all USA count (10/(10+50+40))

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with divide values by `sum`, for correct order of column is used [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df = (df.pivot('Country','AgeRepartition','Count')
        .reindex(columns=df['AgeRepartition'].unique(), index=df['Country'].unique()))
df = df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0).mul(100)
print (df)
AgeRepartition   above 20  less than 20   above 50
Country                                           
USA             10.000000     50.000000  40.000000
Canada          55.555556     11.111111  33.333333
```

Another solution for same order in new index values and in new columns with ordered categoricals:

```
df['Country'] = pd.Categorical(df['Country'], 
                               ordered=True, 
                               categories=df['Country'].unique())
df['AgeRepartition'] = pd.Categorical(df['AgeRepartition'], 
                                      ordered=True, 
                                      categories=df['AgeRepartition'].unique())
df = df.pivot('Country','AgeRepartition','Count')
df = df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0).mul(100)
print (df)
AgeRepartition   above 20  less than 20   above 50
Country                                           
USA             10.000000     50.000000  40.000000
Canada          55.555556     11.111111  33.333333
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)+[`pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html), in the pipe, divide by the sum per row and multiply by 100:

```
df2 = (df
 .pivot(index='Country', columns='AgeRepartition', values='Count')
 .pipe(lambda d: d.div(d.sum(axis=1), axis=0).mul(100))
)
```

output:

```
AgeRepartition  above 20  above 50  less than 20
Country                                         
Canada             55.56     33.33         11.11
USA                10.00     40.00         50.00
```

Answer (score 1):

Another ways is to use `groupby` + `transform(sum)` + `rdiv` to find the percentages, use `assign` to assign it back; then `pivot`:

```
out = (df.assign(Count=df.groupby('Country')['Count'].transform('sum').rdiv(df['Count']).mul(100)
                 .astype(int).astype(str).add('%'))
       .pivot(*df).reset_index().rename_axis(columns=[None]))
```

Output:

```
  Country above 20 above 50 less than 20
0  Canada      55%      33%          11%
1  USA         10%      40%          50%
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest ways is the .pivot_table from pandas library

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.pivot_table(index=['Country'], columns='AgeRepartition', values='Count' aggfunc='first')
```